# Serial port Data to Textbox in vb.net Detailed

Tags: vb.net, arduino, textbox

I'm having a problem with my vb.net application which uses RFID MFRC522 and Arduino to Visual Basic. The data from the Arduino serial port is successfully sent to VB.net textbox. If the textbox received specific data from the Arduino, the UUID of the card tag only, the data from SQL is retrieved if there's a matching card tag.

There's no problem retrieving data and saving automatically when scanned. The only problem is when I scan the RFID tag. The UUID is transferred to a textbox and there's no data coming out to the labels. But when I click the end of the UUID card tag inside the textbox and click the Backspace key, the data is retrieved. I just want the scanned tag to be automatically retrieved and display the data...

This is the code :

```
Private Sub Students_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  loadtable()
  Timer2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
  Dim StringIn As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
  Me.Invoke(Sub() studtag.Text = StringIn) 'we need to invoke since we're on another thread
End Sub

Private Sub studtag_TextChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles studtag.TextChanged
  If studtag.TextLength = 8 Then
    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
    Dim query As String
    query = "select * from dat.students"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Try
      con.Open()
      'Gets or sets an SQL statement or stored procedure used to select records in the database.
      With cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "SELECT * from students where `studtags`='" & studtag.Text & "';"
      End With
      da.SelectCommand = cmd
      da.Fill(table)
      'it gets the data from specific column and fill it into Label
      studtag.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(0)
      idno.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(1)
      lastxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(2)
      firstxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(3)
      middletxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(4)
      dob.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(6)
      agetxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(7)
      crsetxt.Text = table.Rows(0).Item(9)
      tagtxt.Text = studtag.Text
      timein.Text = times.Text
      dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      dr.Read()
      If dob.Text = datenow.Text Then
        greet.Text = "Happy Birthday To You"
      End If
      Dim img() As Byte = CType(dr("studpic"), Byte())
      Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(img)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
      End Using
      insert()
      loadtable()
      Catch ex As Exception
        Notenrolled.Show()
      Finally
      con.Dispose()
      con.Close()
    End Try
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub insert()
  con = New MySqlConnection
  con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
  Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
  Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
  Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
  mstream.Close()
  Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query3 As String
    query3 = "insert into dat.studlogs (studtags,idno,lastxt,firstxt,middletxt,dob,log,age,timein,crse,studpic) values ('" & tagtxt.Text & "','" & idno.Text & "','" & lastxt.Text & "','" & firstxt.Text & "','" & middletxt.Text & "','" & dob.Text & "','" & log.Text & "','" & agetxt.Text & "','" & timein.Text & "','" & crsetxt.Text & "',@studpic)"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query3, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studpic", arrImage)
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
      con.Dispose()
    End Try
  End Sub

  Public Sub loadtable()
    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=dat"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbDataset As New DataTable
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Try
      con.Open()
      Dim query3 As String
      query3 = "select studtags,idno,lastxt,firstxt,middletxt,dob,log,age,timein,crse from dat.studlogs"
      cmd = New MySqlCommand(query3, con)
      SDA.SelectCommand = cmd
      SDA.Fill(dbDataset)
      bSource.DataSource = dbDataset
      DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
      SDA.Update(dbDataset)
      DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(8), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
      con.Close()
      Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
      Finally
        con.Dispose()
      End Try
    End Sub
```

The Arduino code:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Instance of the class
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
// Init array that will store new NUID
byte nuidPICC[4];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Look for new cards
  if (! rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    return;
  // Verify if the NUID has been read
  if (! rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    nuidPICC[i] = rfid.uid.uidByte[i];
  }
  printHex(rfid.uid.uidByte, rfid.uid.size);
  Serial.println();
  rfid.PICC_HaltA();
  rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
}

void printHex(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0":"");
    Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the data received from the Arduino must be 8 digits or characters. For example the data from my serial monitor in Arduino is 7B6BA321. It matches, so the process begins. But it failed to retrieve the data... I need to click the end of the text in textbox and click backspace to retrieve. Additionally when I click backspace the 8-character data from the textbox did not change or delete the last letter or number and retrieve.

I must click backspace twice to delete a one letter and if I input 8 characters manually it will be retrieved from the database. I already tried the other events instead of textchanged and I failed. Please help me. If you have questions feel free to comment.

I will provide a screen capture.

[image: Before I click the backspace in the last letter]
[image: After I click]

Comment: Serial readers usually append a 0x10, 0x13 or both to the string (for authomatic insertion). That is they append a line feed and/or carriage return to the string. Try parse the string you receive.

Comment: Hello @Jimi Thank you for the suggestion but how can I use parse? Can you give me a basic line example? Thank you

Comment: It depends. Is it that studtag.Text that receive the string you are talking about? If so, try  _string As String = studtag.Text.Replace(Chr(10), "").Replace(Chr(13), "")

Comment: Thanks @Jimi I will check it out. Last question where do I place that statement? is it inside the datareceived event? Doesn't need to erase anything ?

Comment: If that is the issue, which is easy to check out, its _natural_ placement is in `SerialPort1_DataReceived` after `Dim StringIn As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()` you can write `StringIn.Replace(Chr(10), "").Replace(Chr(13), "")` so you strip line feeds before they get to the textbox (which, BTW, seems to be set to MultiLine).

Comment: @Jimi I see. I get it thank you. I will try it hope it worked :D. I'm tired of clicking backspace every ID tag scanned. God bless

Comment: Maybe I better specify that this method creates a new string, so the complete code should be `StringIn = StringIn.Replace(Chr(10), "").Replace(Chr(13), "")`

Comment: Okay sir , I already thought about that the problem is about the 0x10 0X13 thing which is I don't understand yet. It's from the sketch code in Arduino programming.

Comment: IF that is the issue, the explanation is pretty simple. But, could you solve your problem?

Comment: @Jimi You are amazing sir. It worked You saved me  thank you. This post is RESOLVED

Comment: I'm glad it did. The real point is, it shouldn't have been a problem, because this is the standard behaviour. Almost all serial readers  append a line feed to the output string. So that is not necessary to press "Enter" on the keyboard to accept the input. What is wrong here, is that the textbox that receives the string, has its Multiline property set. It should not. With this setting, the input string is sent to a new line and the "Return" key effect is lost. So, if you have access to the interface programming, change that setting so that the standard behaviour is re-established.

Comment: Addendum: and, of course, remove that line of code you just added to the `SerialPort1_DataReceived` event handler.

Comment: Yeah Thank you @Jimi Now I understand ..